# Formik form submitting empty object

Tags: reactjs, formik

I'm new to react and Formik and I'm trying to create a login form.
For some reason, the request to the API is sent as the default initial object I created.
Here is the code:

```
import { Formik, Form } from 'formik';
import { observe } from 'mobx';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';
import React from 'react';
import { Input , Button } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { useStore } from '../application/stores/store';

export default observer(function LoginForm() {
    const {userStore} = useStore();
    return (
        <Formik
            initialValues={{user:'', password:''}}
            onSubmit={(values) => {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
                userStore.login(values)}
            }
        >
            {({handleSubmit ,isSubmitting})=> (
                <Form className='ui form' onSubmit={handleSubmit} autoComplete='off'>
                    <Input name='user' placeholder='User'/>
                    <Input name='password' placeholder='Password' type='password'/>
                    <Button loading={isSubmitting} positive content ='Login' type='submit' fluid/>
                </Form>
            )
        }
        </Formik>
    )    
})
```

and here is the result:

```
{
  "user": "",
  "password": ""
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use handleChange from formik

[Please see this](https://formik.org/docs/tutorial#a-simple-newsletter-signup-form)

```
export default observer(function LoginForm() {
    const {userStore} = useStore();
    return (
        <Formik
            initialValues={{user:'', password:''}}
            onSubmit={(values) => {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
                userStore.login(values)}
            }
        >
            {({handleSubmit ,isSubmitting,handleChange})=> (
                <Form className='ui form' onSubmit={handleSubmit} autoComplete='off'>
                    <Input name='user' placeholder='User' onChange={handleChange}/>
                    <Input name='password' placeholder='Password' type='password' onChange={handleChange}/>
                    <Button loading={isSubmitting} positive content ='Login' type='submit' fluid/>
                </Form>
            )
        }
        </Formik>
    )    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I added `enableReinitialize={true}` and it worked for me.

Example:

```
 <Formik
      initialValues={registrationValues}
      validationSchema={RegisterValidationSchema}
      onSubmit={submitHandlerRegister}
      enableReinitialize={true}
    >
   .....
```